# Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Common and Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Services dll missing in c#

Tags: c#

Actually i want to use solver in my C# application. To add it as reference i downloaded and installed [solver dll download](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/hh145003)  in this site .
Then in my project i selected

**`Add->Reference->Browse->MicrosoftSolverFoundationForExcel.dll`** . 
Now if i try to use `using Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Common;`
and **using `Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Services;`** , it is giving error while compiling. But if i use **using `Microsoft.SolverFoundation`** it is not giving any errors. Please guide me how to add these missing dll's.

Comment: Check version of .Net environment

Comment: Wich dll of Microsoft.SolverFoundation you already added?

Comment: im using visual studio 2013 , and i added MicrosoftSolverFoundationForExcel.dll which is downloaded from the site mentioned in my question

Comment: i think need to install "Microsoft.Solver.Foundation.dll" but that is not available in my microsoft solver foundation folder

Answer (score 0):

After a long struggle I found the answer. Just go to `Add reference->Assemblies->Framework->Microsoft Solver Foundation - Express Edition` and check the check box. Thats it!